# Postgres unassigned record, is there a way to test for null?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, sql-null

Is there some way to test an unassigned record for null? (Sorry, sqlfiddle doesn't like my DO block.) Thanks.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
r record;
BEGIN

r := null;

if r is null    -- ERROR:  record "r" is not assigned yet
then
end if;

END
$$;
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/825   You need to change the terminator from ";" so it doesn't get confused by the semicolons in the do block body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error can be avoided by writing:

```
   select null into r;
```

or alternatively:

```
   r:=row(null);
```

such that `r` gets initialized with a tuple structure.

Still, be aware that record variables are unintuitive in other of ways concerning NULLs, and more generally hard to work with outside of their base use case (cursor-style iterating).

Comment: I never even though to try something like this. Thanks ! I'm actually trying to loop trough a set of data and split into two sets of data, so it is sort of like a cursor (I guess.)

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the test with an exception handler you can use the "not initialized" error to do the check for you.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
r record;
BEGIN

r := null;

  BEGIN
    IF r IS NOT NULL THEN
        raise notice 'R IS INITIALIZED';
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise notice 'R IS NOT INITIALIZED';
  END;

END
$$;
```

Comment: My alternative is to declare a boolean to track the initialized status of the record, which would be more error-prone but maybe more readable than exceptions (eventually I'm going to have a long list of if...elsif... statements testing a number of different variables.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from t
where id = p_id
into r;

if found then
...
else
...
end if;
```

https://www.solvingsoftware.dev/testing-for-an-empty-record-variable-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

I would couple that var with the bool variable and set bool variable whenever record is set:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
r record;
rSet bool;
BEGIN    

if rSet then  -- it is false at the beginning

end if;

-- whenever r is set do this as well
r := select a,b;
rSet = true;

-- whenever that value was consumed, set it to "NULL" again:
return next r.a, r.b;
rSet = false;

END
$$;
```